# Issue in aligning the custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

I am just trying to implement a customView from scratch i.e by extending the view class and overriding the onDraw() method. Just trying to build a simple view, a view which just draws a circle for now. I am facing some issue in aligning it and i am not able to understand how android is calculating the views dimensions. 
  Just having only the view i.e setContentView(new MyCustomView(this)) works fine... it takes the entire space and draws the circle. But if i impose any constraints i.e giving margin, or aligning it in centreparent makes my view completely lost and it doesnt draw anything. The issue is the view is getting clipped by its parent but not able to understand why its getting clipped. Any help around this would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

Here is my customView

```
    public class MyCustomView extends View {

    private Paint myPaint=null;
    private boolean useCenters;
    private float xCoordinate;
    private float yCoordinate;
    private float viewWidth;
    private float viewHeight;
    private int totalTime;
    private static float SWEEP_INC ;
    private RectF myRect;
    private boolean shouldInvalidate;
    private float mSweep;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initPaintComponents();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    private void initPaintComponents() {

        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        myPaint.setColor(0x880000FF);
        useCenters = false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        calculateCoordinates();
    }

    private void calculateCoordinates() {

        xCoordinate = getX();
        yCoordinate = getY();
        viewWidth = getWidth();
        viewHeight = getHeight();
        myRect = new RectF(xCoordinate+3, yCoordinate+3, xCoordinate+viewWidth-(viewWidth/10), yCoordinate+viewHeight-(viewHeight/10));
        Log.i("SAMPLEARC","xcoordinate: "+xCoordinate+" ycoordinate: "+yCoordinate+" view width:"+viewWidth+" view height:"+viewHeight+" measured width: "+getMeasuredWidth()+"measured height:"+getMeasuredHeight());
    }

    public int getTotalTime() {
        return totalTime;
    }

    public void setTotalTime(int totalTime) {
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
        SWEEP_INC = (float)6/totalTime;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(myRect, 0, mSweep, useCenters, myPaint);

         mSweep += SWEEP_INC;
         if(mSweep > 280)
         {
             myPaint.setColor(0x888800FF);
         }

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

MyActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MyCustomView myView = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.customimg);
        myView.setTotalTime(10);
    }
```

main.xml

```
  RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
   com.example.anim.MyCustomView android:id="@+id/customimg"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

if i remove that centerInParent in xml it gets drawn. so callling setMeasureDimentions() in onMeasure() doesnt have any affect either. But the xcoodinate,ycoordinate,viewWidth and viewHeight seems to give the correct values. Just need to understand why the view is getting clipped and how android is calculating the dimensions at runtime. And how do i consider the margin paramters while drawing these customViews. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see this it will help you to solve your problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205838/how-to-draw-circle-with-partitioned-in-android

Comment: Hi Himanshu thanks for your help.... but i am actually not trying to draw a static circle....i am palnning to design my own customview which would be similar to any View in android (textview,edittext), a re-usable view which i can use in any application and can include in any xml.  Is there anything that i am missing in onMeasure() of my view? do i have to consider any other parameters while calculating the dimensions of my rectF?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:lib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <com.ind.Custom_Attribute.LibView  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
  android:text=""
  lib:xattr="Custom attribute APPLIED!"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Shivang, i am not able to understand what you mean exactly. can you please let me know what exactly you want me to change?

Comment: this line is for custom Attribute

Comment: lib:xattr="Custom attribute APPLIED!"

Comment: this is how to use this custom link, here it is name with lib so use lib:

Comment: Hi shivang, thanks for your help... but i am not trying to add custom properties to my custom view rather i am trying to make my view work with existing parameters/attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="CustomAttrs">
    <attr name="xattr" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

in values/attrs.xml

Comment: this is for adding extra paramters to the custom component. But thats not my case... i want the existing parameters(margin,centerinparent) to work with my custom view.thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there anything that i am missing in onMeasure() of my view? do i have to consider any other parameters while calculating the dimensions of my rectF?