# how to rotate partitioned circle in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have drawn a partitioned circle in android . I want to know is there any way in which I can rotate that circle. I drawn the circle from the code obtained from the following link and I made changes to that code to draw text in each arc:
[How to draw circle with partitioned in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205838/how-to-draw-circle-with-partitioned-in-android)

Can anyone help me in rotating that circle.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate your `canvas` with :

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angleInDegrees);
// Do your drawing
canvas.restore();
```

You have to save and restore your canvas if you want to draw something else but not rotated.